# How do I add qtip to kendo grid for ellipsed words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Below is how I structured my kendo grid:

```
CreateListGrid: function () {
            $("#PlanListGrid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read:{
                            url: BrowserSide.Url.getFullUrl("PlanningList/ReadPlans"),
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                searchVal: $('#category').val(),
                                status: $('#ListFilterType').val(),
                            },
                        },                       
                        dataType: "json",
                    },
                    pageSize: 10,

                    schema: {
                        data: "Data",
                        total: "Total",
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                FirstName: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                LastName: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                Title: { editable: false },
                                Id: { editable: false }
                            }
                        },
                        errors: "Errors"
                    },
                },
                toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
                selectable: "row",
                //groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                //scrollable:true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: "FirstName",
                    title: "First Name",
                    width: 160,
                    template: "#= SearchItems_Highlight(FirstName)#"
                }, {
                    field: "LastName",
                    title: "Last Name",
                    width: 160,
                    template: "#= SearchItems_Highlight(LastName)#"
                },
                {
                    field: "Title",
                    title: "Plan Title",
                    width: 180,
                    template: "#= SearchItems_Highlight(Title)#"
                }, 
                {
                    field: "Id",
                    title: "Id",
                    width: 0
                },
                ]
            });
            var grid = $("#PlanListGrid").data("kendoGrid");

            grid.hideColumn("Id");
            $("#PlanListGrid > .k-grid-header").css({ "padding-right": "0px;" });

        }
```

I have the text fields in my kendo grid ellipsed if they are too long for the column width. Now I am having trouble adding a qtip to the ellipsed words in my kendo grid.

EDIT:

Because I'm lazy, I found a similar example online using kendo grid. I added the style for .k-grid td which is similar to what I have now that ellipses the text if it's too long. My question now is how do I add a jquery qtip to the ellipsed text? Rather where in the code should I add the qtip?

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owlstack/Sbb5Z/1608/)

Comment: mind posting a working example link? a fiddle would be fab.

Comment: Because I'm lazy, I found a similar example online using kendo grid. I added the style for .k-grid td which is similar to what I have now that ellipses the text if it's too long. My question now is how do I add a jquery qtip to the ellipsed text? Rather where in the code should I add the qtip? Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/owlstack/Sbb5Z/1608/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply qtip after grid creation.

```
function applyTooltip() {
    $(".k-grid-content tbody td").each(function (index, element) {
        var td = $(element);
        td.qtip({
            content: td.text(),
            //hide: { when: 'unfocus', delay: 100 },
            style: {
                border: {
                    width: 1,
                    radius: 10
                },
                padding: 2,
                textAlign: 'center',
                tip: true,
                name: 'cream'
            },
            position: {
                adjust: {
                    screen: true
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/1610/

You can restrict qTip to columns who have data exceed a certain number of characters (ellipsis)
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/1611/

Comment: Okay I'll take a deeper look but it should only be applied to the words that are ellipsed and not all the words. Thanks :D

Comment: Please mark the answer accepted if it helped you. This was just to give you a start.....you can now modify it on your own :)

Comment: I have added the ellipsis only solution, please check.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will double check with my current code and see it works because it doesn't work for the code above for some reason. Only the fiddle.

Comment: @KalaJ: you haven't included the qTip js in the fiddle. please include it in external resources.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. The problem for me is this solution still doesn't work in my original code. I'm not sure why. I'm positiive you have it correct because it works when I run it in the console but not in my actually code without running it in console? What could that mean?